# Access a reducer from a different reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

I have a list of pupils and my app always shows one pupil at the time, the activePupil. I have two reducers thus far. One contains and by default returns a list of all the children (in the form of an array):

```
[ 
 {
    id: 1
    name: Barack
 },
 {
    id: 2
    name: Donald
 }
]
```

...then I have a activePupilReducer, which contains the current pupil being viewed. So e.g.

```
 {
    id: 2
    name: Donald
 }
```

Now I do not know how to iterate to the next student. When the action "UPDATE_ACTIVE" is dispatched, I want my activePupilReducer to update the active Student to the next student. So I would need to grab the current id of my student, iterate it, and then grab the student with the right id from the other reducer (or that's what I assume I must do). Right now my activePupilReducer looks like this:

```
export default function (state={id: -1, name:"John"}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
      case "UPDATE_ACTIVE":
        // ??
      default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

I would somehow need to grab the other reducer and grab the next element, but I have no idea how I would go about this.

Answer (score 1):

seems to me that the active pupil and list of pupils inherently should live inside the same reducer. So for example just have a pupil reducer whose state is an object. Then have your actions as you do currently.

Also having said that, reducers are meant to be pure from any side effects and thus isn't the place do what you are looking to do. What you could do is compute the next student outside of your reducer/action for example on button click in some component and then pass it along to your update_active action which then passes it into your reducer to set as the active pupil.

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, I am completely on the wrong track, trying to implement this function in the reducer? It's funny, because I currently have it in my action, but thought I was implementing an anti-pattern there.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your `activePupilReducer` is not wide enough. It should be able to see both the `activePupil` key and the `pupils` array to work.

If you're using `combineReducers`, you're probably not giving them access to each other's state. You should merge these two reducers into one, and use the following state structure:

```
{
  pupils: [...]
  activePupil: {...}
}
```

When you invoke the `UPDATE_ACTIVE` action, this single reducer with have access to both keys and be able to perform the state mutation.

Comment: I am using combine reducers, so, in the end, my store looks like the one you are citing. Would I then, if i understand you correctly, simply implement this function in my combined-reducer, as I need access to both pieces of data?

Comment: Your reducer should have access to **both** entries. You need to place **both** under the same key in the store, so they are accessible by the same reducer. So, `store = { data: { pupils, activePupil } }`